# Django user-specific variable not updating in backend

Tags: python, django, variables

I have a set a pre-existing teams that the user can join [team1, team2, team3] at /jointeam, and that will show up on /home.

My issue is that the variable 'user_team' from Profile stays 'None', even after the user successfully joins a team.

In other words, if I enter '**team1**' on /jointeam , I'd like it to assign it to **user.profile.user_group**

Thanks in advance, appreciate your input!

Here is my code:

**Models.py**

```
#used to create a team
class TeamCreation(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, unique=True)
[...]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

#user-specific
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_team = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
[...]
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

#model to join a team
class Join(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

**Forms.py**

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class TeamCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamCreation
        fields=['team_name']

class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Join
        fields=['team_name']
```

**views.py - users**

```
[...]
@login_required
def join_team(request):
        form_class = JoinForm
        form_join = form_class(request.POST or None)      
        user = request.user

        if request.method=='POST':


            if form_join.is_valid():
                newJoin = form_join.save(commit=False)

                if not TeamCreation.objects.filter(team_name=newJoin.team_name).exists():
                    print("nope")
                    return redirect('dashboard')
                    messages.error("Team doesn't exist or incorrect key")

                else:
                    print("exist")

                    group_name=newJoin.team_name            

                    user.profile.user_team=group_name


                    newJoin.save()

                    return redirect('dashboard')



            else:
                print("Error")

        context={
                "form":form_join,
                }

        return render(request, "pages/join_team.html", context)

@login_required
def home(request):

    user = request.user
    group_name=user.profile.user_team

    context={
            "user_group":group_name,
            }

    return render(request,'pages/dashboard.html', context)
```

**Home.html**

```
[...]                                                                         
{% if user_team %}

<option>{{ user_team }}</option>
                                                                                                                                                            <option>Join a team</option>

<option>Create a team</option>

{% else %}

<option>-- none</option>
                                                                                                                                                           <option>Join a team</option>

<option>Create a team</option>

{% endif %}
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the profile after updating it.

```
group_name = newJoin.team_name
newJoin.save()
user.profile.user_team = group_name
user.profile.save()
```

It's probably a better idea to save the profile after the join instance has been created in case it fails.